# Integrating adMob: Error: Thread 1: Fatal error:

Tags: swift, admob, swift4

I am trying to add admob to my app but I get an error.

Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

I have followed along on developer.google.com and on stackoverflow.com but I can't seem to fix it.

Here is my code:

import UIKit
import GoogleMobileAds

class ViewController: UIViewController, GADBannerViewDelegate {

```
//Place your instance variables here
let allQuestions = QuestionBank()
var pickedAnswer : Bool = false
var questionNumber : Int = 0
var score : Int = 0
var bannerView: GADBannerView!
var banner: GADBannerView!


@IBOutlet weak var questionLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var scoreLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var GoogleBannerView: GADBannerView!

@IBOutlet weak var progressLabel: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    banner = GADBannerView(frame: self.view.frame)
    GADMobileAds.configure(withApplicationID: "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716")
    bannerView.adUnitID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716"       ***//Crashes Here***
    bannerView.rootViewController = self
    bannerView.load(GADRequest())
    bannerView.delegate = self

    /// Tells the delegate an ad request loaded an ad.
    func adViewDidReceiveAd(_ bannerView: GADBannerView) {
        print("adViewDidReceiveAd")
    }

    /// Tells the delegate an ad request failed.
    func adView(_ bannerView: GADBannerView,
                didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: GADRequestError) {
        print("adView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

    /// Tells the delegate that a full-screen view will be presented in response
    /// to the user clicking on an ad.
    func adViewWillPresentScreen(_ bannerView: GADBannerView) {
        print("adViewWillPresentScreen")
    }

    /// Tells the delegate that the full-screen view will be dismissed.
    func adViewWillDismissScreen(_ bannerView: GADBannerView) {
        print("adViewWillDismissScreen")
    }

    /// Tells the delegate that the full-screen view has been dismissed.
    func adViewDidDismissScreen(_ bannerView: GADBannerView) {
        print("adViewDidDismissScreen")
    }

    /// Tells the delegate that a user click will open another app (such as
    /// the App Store), backgrounding the current app.
    func adViewWillLeaveApplication(_ bannerView: GADBannerView) {
        print("adViewWillLeaveApplication")
    }

    bannerView = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeBanner)

    addBannerViewToView(bannerView)

    nextQuestion()
}

func addBannerViewToView(_ bannerView: GADBannerView) {
    bannerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.addSubview(bannerView)
    view.addConstraints(
        [NSLayoutConstraint(item: bannerView,
                            attribute: .bottom,
                            relatedBy: .equal,
                            toItem: bottomLayoutGuide,
                            attribute: .top,
                            multiplier: 1,
                            constant: 0),
         NSLayoutConstraint(item: bannerView,
                            attribute: .centerX,
                            relatedBy: .equal,
                            toItem: view,
                            attribute: .centerX,
                            multiplier: 1,
                            constant: 0)
        ])
}
```

Thanks for anyone who can help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two objects of type GADBannerView (banner and bannerView) and it looks like you're mixing them.

You're trying to set adUnitId of bannerView but have never instantiated this one.

Comment: I got rid of the banner but it still shows an error

Comment: Can you edit your question with the new code so I can see what you've done ?